# getting KeyError: '' with request url

Tags: python

have a file `tmodule.py`  contains a dictionary of URL's.when try to call it  with  specific URL id, get an error.
code looks like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
def stock(self, stockname="", value=100):
stocknames = {
    "ABAD1": "59612098290740355",
    "ABDI1": "49054891736433700",
}


 urlid = stocknames[stockname]
    url = 'http://.............................&i=' + urlid
    content = requests.get(url)
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for line in content.iter_lines():
            writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
    df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
    return (....)
```

above code has no error but when i try to pass a key like:

```
import tmodule as tm
st=tm.stock("ABAD1")
```

got this error :

```
File "D:\anaconda\envs\geo_env\Lib\site-packages\..........", line 323, in stock  


urlid = stocknames[stockname]

KeyError: ''
```

it's a long dictionary and i just copy two key and value here

Comment: Please, provide [mre].

Answer (score 1):

It looks this is regular function, not a method in a class (as implied by first parameter `self`). When you pass `"ABAD1"` as positional argument when call `st=tm.stock("ABAD1")` it is bind to `self` and `stockname` remains with default value of `""`.
Unless you provide a reason for `self` being first parameter, just remove it.

```
def stock(stockname="", value=100):
```

Comment: it's a python module and i installed it on my system and when delete `self` get another error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/site-packages/....py", line 2, in <module>
    foolad=tm.stock("FOLD1")
  File "D:\asite-packages\\.....py", line 329, in stock
    writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
  File "C:\Users\.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 48: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: This is completely different error, not caused by removing `self` from your function, but how you process the response when write to file. Ask a separate question, providing [mre], sample of the response you get, the full traceback, etc.